# Why is window still defined in this strict mode code?

Tags: javascript

```
"use strict";

setTimeout(function() {"use strict";console.log(this)}, 1000);
```

The 'this' inside functions called by setTimeout should refer to global object, but I also have "use strict"; in the body. Yet it logs window instead of undefined, which is what I was expecting. What's happening here?

Comment: where do you learn that window is not defined in strict mode?

Comment: I didn't. I learned that "this" that refers to the global object is undefined.

Comment: @bingjie2680: This is what he's referring to: http://jsfiddle.net/LfT3x/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`setTimeout` is defined](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers) as calling the function it is passed in the context of `window`.

> the object on which the method for which the algorithm is running is implemented (a Window or WorkerGlobalScope object) as the method context,

It is akin to calling `yourfunction.apply(window)` not `yourfunction()`.

Comment: Nicely put! It is worth mentioning that NodeJS implements a slightly different timers API, and for obvious reasons it doesn't set the `this` value to the window. It instead sets the `this` value to the timeout object itself (what you call clearTimeout on in the browser, in the browser it's just a number and in Node it's an object). Also, as specified in the answer note that when running in a web worker it isn't set to the `window` object for obvious security reasons but to the worker global scope.

Answer (score 4):

Now it's almost 4 years after the question.

There has been a note in [MDN setTimeout page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), which precisely addresses this question.

> The default `this` value of a `setTimeout` callback will ***`still`*** be the
>   `window` object, and not `undefined`, even in strict mode.

This applies to `setInterval` too, even though it is not mentioned [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Answer (score 2):

because this actually:

```
  window.setTimeout(function() {"use strict";console.log(this)}, 1000);
```

you call setTimeout with window-object actually despite the fact that you are not writing it.

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't this inside the callback function still be undefined?

Comment: Good question too, I think the context remains the same. Because the callback-function is called within setTimeout.

Comment: @ZackGao no, it shouldn't. Check the es5 spec and the DOM timers API.

Comment: This is not the reason that the function runs with `this` set to the global context (`window`).  It works the way it does simply because that's the way it was implemented.

Comment: @ZackGao: It would, except for the fact that `setTimeout` explicitly sets the `this` value to `window`. Think of it as `callback.call(window, ...)`; Just like in event handlers, where `this` refers to the element that received the event.

Comment: The wording in this answer really makes no sense.