# Why does this not log undefined to the console when run in Chrome's console window?

Tags: javascript, strict-mode

```
(function (){
  'use strict';
  function Foo() { 
    this.foo = function() { 
      setTimeout(function(){ console.log(this); }, 0);
    } 
  }
  new Foo().foo();
}())
```

If I had not declared strict mode then the global object would be printed to the console (i.e. window).

**BUT**, given that strict mode is declared, I was expecting undefined to be printed to the console.

**Reference:**

> "That means, among other things, that in browsers it's no longer
>   possible to reference the window object through this inside a strict
>   mode function."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript

**Update**: to achieve the expected behavior you need to create a new execution context and refer to this within that context like so:

```
(function (){
  'use strict';
  function Foo() { 
    this.foo = function() { 
      setTimeout(function(){ (function() { console.log(this); }()) }, 0);
    } 
  }
  new Foo().foo();
}())
```

Comment: It's logging undefined in firefox and chrome console....

Comment: because, `this` when there is no context, is set to the global object, which in browsers is `window`

Comment: But in strict mode, such a situation is guarded against, is it not?

Comment: Undefined is the expression return value, it does print window object(Chrome 37).

Comment: Sorry correction, using setTimeout basically runs the passed function as if .apply was used with window http://stackoverflow.com/a/21957112/560593, so it does have a context

Comment: Both using strict mode or without using, the output is coming same to me....

Comment: @PatrickEvans does node.js exhibit the same behavior with setTimeout?

Comment: @Ben, personally I do not know, but since there is no window object i would expect it to be set to something different, and from the comment on the linked answer it seems to be set to the timer object instead of a window object, and in web workers the worker global object.

Comment: @PatrickEvans OK thanks. My tests with Node appear to confirm.